# How to prevent GTK inspector from opening when opening an app from the terminal?

Tags: gtk, gtkinspector

Very often, when I open an app through the terminal, the GTK inspector also gets opened for that app. Firefox doesn't seem to and VS Code usually closes it on its own. But otherwise, running `~$ vlc` or `~$ qdirstat` and the like opens the inspector. Is there any way to turn this off?

When Googling around, I seem to only be able to find methods of opening the inspector, which is the opposite of what I want.

Comment: How do you open the app(s)? What command?

Comment: I, for example, open VSCode with the command `code`.

Comment: Is there a `GTK_DEBUG` environment variable in your terminal session (check with `printenv | grep GTK_` for example)? if so, what is its value?

Comment: Ah! `GTK_DEBUG` is set to `interactive`. I'm not sure how I missed it when I was searching around, it's listed pretty clearly under https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/running.html#gtk_debug. I'm a bit embarrassed it was that easy, but hindsight is 20/20 and all. Thanks so much @steeldriver. Would you like to write an answer so I can mark yours as accepted? Or I can do it myself if you'd like, not sure how etiquette works around here.

Comment: @WadeCheng why don't you do it yourself, since you have all the info at your fingertips. FWIW I'm guessing your firefox is unaffected because it is contained within a snap.

Comment: Sounds about right. Cheers o7 @steeldriver

Answer (score 6):

(Thanks to @steeldriver)

The `GTK_DEBUG` environment variable in my terminal session was set to `interactive`. Putting `unset GTK_DEBUG` at the bottom of my `~/.bashrc` fixed it.

One may check via `echo $GTK_DEBUG` or `printenv | grep GTK_` to list any variable starting with `GTK_`.

Comment: Instead of unsetting it, I'd recommend figuring out why it is set in the first place. That is not the default. It probably is set in your bashrc or some file sourced from it.